# Dataform: incremental merge updating all columns except a specific column

Tags: google-bigquery, dataform

I pretend to run a merge over a BigQuery table, through a Dataform incremental model, but I don't want to update all the columns in the target table, I want to update everything except a specific column (because I want to keep the first insert_time value for every row, I don't want to overwrite this value even if the row had changes in other columns).

I know how to do it through a BigQuery merge statement, but I want to do it with a Dataform incremental model, and I don't see how it can be achieved (I don't see how to specify which columns to update in the merge).

Comment: I would like to do it as well - but didn't find how